# Magento Multisite (Subfolder) Blank Page

Tags: multistore, magento-1.9

Today, I want to creat a new Website (Multisite - Subfolder method) for my Magento Page. (I'm working on a running Server).

What I have done:

1. I Created a new Root - Subcategory (store2)
2. I created a new Webstide in Magento/System/Configuration/Manage Stores
   (I'm working on a running Server):

Website     ->      name: mystore2    ,            code: mystore2

Store       ->      name: Main Store  ,   ROOT Category: store2

Store View  ->      name: English     ,            code: mystore2_en 
                 ,Status: enabled

1. I created Subfolders on my Root Server --> name: en
2. Changed URL Secure & Unsecure:

BASE URL: http://mydomain.at/en/

1. I copied index.php and .htaccess to my subfolder
2. Changed Index.php Codes --- My Codes:

   - $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . 'app/Mage.php'; 
     $maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
   - $compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . 'includes/config.php';
     if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
     include $compilerConfig;

---

- /* Store or website code */
  $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run('mystore2', 'website');

---

Now, I got a blank Page... 
Hope anyone can help me!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that just copying the index.php file will not do the trick, because all the app/ folder etc is missing.

To get around this, in your index.php you need to set the MAGENTO_ROOT to be one folder up:

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd() . '/..');
```

Then it should work.

However, you also want to make sure that your skin etc is loaded from the parent folder, so in your Magento backend, you will need to enter http://mydomain.at/ instead of http://mydomain.at/en/ for skin, images etc in the URL management.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made a screenshot for you with the settings. Instead of /ru, for you it is /en of course: http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30mbdxl&s=8#.U6rLON9kcvR

Answer (score 0):

I happened to same problem with yours, I find my solution, very simple, just because you doesn't set the CMS->Page->'Home Page' correctly, you need to assign this home page to your new website as well, otherwise no home page to show then just blank page.

hope this can help you